# PHP loop not working

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Here is what i got:

```php
 $pagecount=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 echo '<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);">';
    while ($pagecount < 3) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . $pagecount . '</div></div>';
        $pagecount++;
        }
    }
$pagecount=0;
echo '</div>';
}
```

The problem is that when this is run, it will print out $victim, $cod and then $pagecount. I never want pagecount to be higher than 3, so i put in the while statement, so when it hits 3 it should exit out of the loop, and then pagecount should go back to 0 and then start increasing again. however when this is run, pagecount just keeps on getting higher, and doesn't hit 3 and then go back to 0. Can anyone help?? Is there something wrong with my condition or loop or something?

Also just on the side, can anyone tell me instead of using the first `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` is there something i can use to check if the result wont be empty, because at the moment, it will skip the first entry in the mysql db.

Cheers guys!

**EDIT:** Tested everyones solution so far, and they all worked for me.
It just shows how there are many different ways you can do one thing!

Thank you everyone, you were all very, very helpful. Much appreciated. :)
What i ended up going was completley removing the whole `while` statement from the inner loop.

However because of the first `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` there first DB entry is still getting skipped.
Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$pagecount=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);">';
    while($pagecount < 3 && $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . $pagecount . '</div></div>';
       $pagecount++;
    }
    $pagecount=0;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` inside a loop using `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` will make the pointer of your result to go too forward.
I advice you to store all the objects in an array before performing your loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($pagecount < 3) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . $pagecount . '</div></div>';
        $pagecount++;
        }
    }
```

Your inner while will keep looping as long as it can fetch_assoc, because you don't check the pagecount.

Move the condition to the inner while:

```
    while($pagecount < 3 && $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . $pagecount . '</div></div>';
        $pagecount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagecount++;
```

should be moved out of the inner loop, i.e.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div     class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . $pagecount . '</div></div>';
    //moved 1 level: $pagecount++;
    }
$pagecount++;
}
```

indenting your code might have helped :)

Comment: ahh someone else formatted the code, the original had the 2 while loops at the same level of indentation